# How to change a raster to a specific spatial resolution?

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I would like to change the resolution of a raster. For example, let’s take
this Landsat 7 images at ~ 30m resolution.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21

f <- system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
r <- rast(f)

# 30m x 30m resolution
res(r)
#> [1] 28.5 28.5

plot(r, 1)
```

[image]

I can use `aggregate()` with an integer factor such as:

```r
# 10 * 28.5
r2 <- aggregate(r, fact = 10)
res(r2)
#> [1] 285 285

plot(r2, 1)
```

[image]

My question is, how can I specify an *exact resolution*. For example, I would
like to have a pixel resolution of 1.234 km (1234 m).

```r
fact <- 1234 / 28.5
fact
#> [1] 43.29825

r3 <- aggregate(r, fact = fact)
res(r3)
#> [1] 1225.5 1225.5

plot(r3, 1)
```

[image]

The documentation says that `fact` should be an integer, so here it is
flooring `fact` to 43.

```r
res(aggregate(r, 43))
#> [1] 1225.5 1225.5
```

Any ways to have an exact resolution of 1234 m?

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: A raster has to be made of regularly sized cells. If your original data has dimensions that are not a multiple of the resolution you choose, then your cells will not equal the extent of the original raster. Putting a fractional number into `aggregate` implies that you want a fractional number of cells in your resulting raster, which doesn't really make sense. Of course, it should be possible if cropping were allowed, but that option doesn't seem to be included. I guess you could crop the raster to a multiple of `fact` _then_ aggregate it?

Comment: Thank you, @AllanCameron, for responding. This is where I am stuck. I do not mind cropping a bit, but I kind of lost here. Do you have any resources or guidance to provide? How can `r` be cropped using a factor? Would it be possible to create a grid of the desired resolution before and "translate" `r` into it?

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution which seems to give me what I need.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21

f <- system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
r <- rast(f)

plot(r, 1)
```

[image]

```r
r2 <- r
res(r2) <- 1234
r2 <- resample(r, r2)

plot(r2, 1)
```

[image]

```r
res(r2)
#> [1] 1234 1234
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I was about to post a very similar solution using `resample`, but this one is just as good!

Comment: Thank you, @AllanCameron. Your previous answer guided me to approach this differently.

Answer (score 1):

I also propose (as described in the terra vignette) that you first aggregate the raster as close as possible and then resample. Resampling can be done e.g. using a template raster to guarantee correct crs, dimensions etc.