# How to dowscale a raster but keeping the same values?

Tags: r, raster, cdo-climate

If I have this raster with 40 x 40 resolution.

```
 library(raster)
 #get some sample data
 data(meuse.grid)
 gridded(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
 meuse.raster <- raster(meuse.grid)
 res(meuse.raster)
 #[1] 40 40
```

I would like to downscale this raster to 4 x 4. If a pixel of 40x40   = 125, so use the same values for all pixels of 4x4x within this pixel.

just divide each pixel of 40 x40 into 4x4 with keeping its value.

I am open to CDO solutions as well.

Comment: Perhaps you want to [resample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044284/how-to-change-a-raster-to-a-specific-spatial-resolution) using `terra`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `raster::disaggregate`

```
library(raster)

#get some sample data
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
meuse.raster <- raster(meuse.grid)

#assign geographic coordinate system (from coordinates and location (Meuse) it seems like the standard projection for the Netherlands (Amersfoort, ESPG:28992)
crs(meuse.raster) <- "EPSG:28992"

#disaggregate
meuse.raster.dissaggregated <- disaggregate(meuse.raster, c(10,10))
```

I used c(10,10) to disaggregated from a 40x40 to 4x4 resolution (10 times more detailed).

```
res(meuse.raster.dissaggregated)
[1] 4 4
```

In the comments Chris mentioned the `terra` package. I also recommend shifting from `raster` to `terra`. I believe its the newest package and will eventually replaces packages like `raster` and `stars`.

`terra` also has a disaggregation function `terra::disagg()` which works in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, so the values will not be changed?

Comment: Indeed, you can save the rasters and open them in for example for a quick check. Documentation of ```terra::disagg()```: Create a SpatRaster with a higher resolution (smaller cells). The values in the new SpatRaster are the same as in the larger original cells. Documentation of ```raster::disaggregate()```: Disaggregate a RasterLayer to create a new RasterLayer with a higher resolution (smaller cells). The values in the new RasterLayer are the same as in the larger original cells unless you specify method="bilinear", in which case values are locally interpolated (using the resample function).